# how is create masked Input with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate, jquery

hos can create masked Input for date and time by jQuery?
i not want use of plugin.

```
like:    
date-> ____/__/__ & time-> __:__
date-> text-algin: right;
time-> text-algin: left;
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a plugin, how about finding a plugin that does this well and look through the source?

Comment: @genesis A masked input only allows for a certain format on input, it's like a really really live validation (sort of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Works well, have used it in the past.

You can 'see how it's done' and take what you need... but that's a bit pointless :)

Comment: Yip, told him to learn from the source of something that does what he wants :)

Comment: this is hectic. please explain